# I am tring to jump to another host using JSch, but it is not working

Tags: java, jsch

I use jsch to connect to a server and it works to send command using Exec and shell channel, now I want to connect to another server through the first connection, but the application crashes when trying to connect the second session, not sure if I set the code correctly or not

```
public Session Connect() throws JSchException{

String host1 = "192.168.1.1";
String host2 = "192.168.2.2";
String username = "host";
String password = "pass";




JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session s;
s = jsch.getSession(username, host1, 22);
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
s.setConfig(config);
s.setPassword(password);
s.connect();
s.setPortForwardingL(22, host2, 22);
Session secondSession = jsch.getSession(username, host2, 22);
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
secondSession.setConfig(config);
secondSession.setPassword(password);
secondSession.connect();

return secondSession;
 }
```

Comment: You say the application crashes? Please [edit] your question to include the complete exception or error message and indicate which line of your code is producing it.

Answer (score 1):

After you declare and assign to `secondSession`, didn't you mean to `setConfig` and `setPassword` on `secondSession`, instead of on `s` again?

```
secondSession.setConfig(config);
secondSession.setPassword(password);
secondSession.connect();
```

Comment: yeah just a typo, I changed it, still no difference